# The call to "get" always fails to index as index is out of bounds

Tags: java

I hope I am not writing here a duplicate question, I tried to look it up but I didn't find anything.

So I have a class with the name Map, for which I try to configure my generator function so that it takes the parameter ListOfLocations together with two more integers width and height.

There is another class named Places, where I give the coordinates from the List of locations and it creates an instance.  And a third one that handles the coordinates.

```
public class Map {

     private ArrayList <ArrayList<Places>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();

     public Map(int width, int height, Collection <Coordinate> places){   
             //Create places
    for (int i=0;i<=width-1;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<=height-1;j++){
            newMap.get(i).add(new Place(new Coordinate(i,j)));
        }
    }
```

The idea is that it goes through all the combinations (i,j) it creates a coordinate and passes that coordinate to the class Place. Since I have my Map as an ArrayList of ArrayLists (I want it in 2D) I try to call a field with **.get**

Ex. when it is handling width *i* it should take the list on position *i* and add a new Place.

But I get a

> The call to "get" always fails as index out of bounds.

The same happens in two other places where I have the **.get** call.

Could someone explain to me where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `newMap` is empty. Hence, when you call `newMap.get(0)`, you get the `OutOfBoundException`

Comment: I thought I got that one covered when I defined it at the beginning
private ArrayList <ArrayList<Places>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Nope. By doing that, it is not-null but is still empty. I think that you misinterpret it because you have a list of list. Consider this example : `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.get(0)'`.

Comment: I believe I understand what you mean. But how could I tell it where to save the new Place if I dont try to "get" that place?

Comment: I believe you want to create a new List for each `i`. I posted an example which shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the list but never populate it :

```
// The List is not null but is actually empty
private ArrayList <ArrayList<Places>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hence, `newMap.get(0)` does not make sense. You get the first element of a list which is empty.

You can do it like this :

```
public class Map {

  private ArrayList <ArrayList<Places>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();

  public Map(int width, int height, Collection <Coordinate> places){

    for (int i=0;i<=width-1;i++){
      ArrayList<Places> list = new ArrayList<Places>();
      for (int j=0;j<=height-1;j++){
        list.add(new Place(new Coordinate(i,j)));
      }
      newMap.add(list);
    }
```

Some advices :

- Don't call your class `Map`, there is already a class with this name and it will bring some confusion.
- When declaring the list, prefer declaring it as a `List` (interface), not an `ArrayList` (the actual implementation).

like this :

```
private List<List<Places>> newMap = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thanks for the complete answer and the tips :) it worked